# Scatterview Items collection not removing an item

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

Can anyone tell me why the item isn't removed from the collection in the following code? It runs through it without throwing but the sv.Count always stays the same and the item never gets removed.

```
public static void FadeOutAndRemove(ScatterView sv, ScatterViewItem svi)
    {
        try
        {
            svi.Opacity = 1.0;

            var a = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = 1.0,
                To = 0.0,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
            };

            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(a);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(a, svi);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

            storyboard.Completed += delegate { 
                    svi.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    sv.Items.Remove(svi);
                    svi.Content = null;
                    svi = null;
            };

            storyboard.Begin();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle error
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `svi` is actually contained in `sv.Items`? The Remove call silently ignores the case where the item to be removed is not contained in the collection.

Comment: And you could save the whole Storyboard stuff and directly call `svi.BeginAnimation`.